# How to get around `'Proxy' object does not support item assignment`

Tags: pytorch, quantization

Here's the line that triggers this error during `torch.quantization.quantize_fx.prepare_fx`

```
patch_embed[:, 1:] = patch_embed[:, 1:] + self.proj(self.norm1_proj(pixel_embed).reshape(B, N - 1, -1))
```

Is there some way to get around this without having to avoid item assignment? Can I somehow inform that particular proxy instance that this should be okay?